# Akka Remote Actor Exception from Enum

Tags: scala, akka

The code below contains a simple Akka remote actors example with two Apps, the `ChipShop` (server) and the `Customer` (client).  It works fine as it is, with the customer sending the order which is printed out, but if I switch the implementation within `ChipShopOrder` to use an Enum then I get an exception (java.io.IOException:unexpected exception type).  Why is this?

Exception:

```
[INFO] [06/21/2012 19:40:54.1] [main] [ActorSystem(ShopSystem)] REMOTE: RemoteServerStarted@akka://ShopSystem@127.0.0.1:2552
[INFO] [06/21/2012 19:41:03.692] [ShopSystem-7] [ActorSystem(ShopSystem)] REMOTE: RemoteClientStarted@akka://CustomerSystem@127.0.0.1:2553
[ERROR] [06/21/2012 19:41:03.796] [ShopSystem-3] [ActorSystem(ShopSystem)] REMOTE: RemoteServerError@akka://ShopSystem@127.0.0.1:2552] Error[java.io.IOException:unexpected exception type
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.throwMiscException(ObjectStreamClass.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1097)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1780)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.init(HashTable.scala:81)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.init(HashMap.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.scala:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$1.apply(Serializer.scala:121)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer.fromBinary(Serializer.scala:121)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.deserialize(Serialization.scala:73)
    at akka.remote.MessageSerializer$.deserialize(MessageSerializer.scala:21)
    at akka.remote.RemoteMessage.payload(RemoteTransport.scala:210)
    at akka.remote.RemoteMarshallingOps$class.receiveMessage(RemoteTransport.scala:276)
    at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport.receiveMessage(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:29)
    at akka.remote.netty.RemoteServerHandler.messageReceived(Server.scala:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
    at akka.remote.netty.RemoteServerHandler.handleUpstream(Server.scala:150)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.StaticChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(StaticChannelPipeline.java:366)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.StaticChannelPipeline$StaticChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(StaticChannelPipeline.java:528)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ChannelUpstreamEventRunnable.run(ChannelUpstreamEventRunnable.java:44)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor$ChildExecutor.run(OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

To run, start the ChipShop app first, then the Customer app.
Source:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import akka.actor.{ ActorSystem, Actor, Props }

object Configs{
    val customerConfig = ConfigFactory.parseString( """
        akka.actor.provider = akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider
        akka.remote.netty.hostname = "127.0.0.1"
        akka.remote.netty.port = 2553
    """)

    val shopConfig = ConfigFactory.parseString( """
        akka.actor.provider = akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider
        akka.remote.netty.hostname = "127.0.0.1"
        akka.remote.netty.port = 2552
    """)
}

class ChipShopOrder extends Serializable{
    // - Working implementation -
    trait Food
    case object Chips extends Food
    case object Fish extends Food
    case class OrderableItem(item: Food, quantity: Int)
    //----------- End -----------

    // -- Broken implementation --
//  object Food extends Enumeration{
//      type Food = Value
//      val Chips, Fish, Sausage = Value
//  }
//  import Food._
//  case class OrderableItem(item: Food.Value, quantity: Int)
    //----------- End ------------

    case class CustomerOrder(items: Seq[OrderableItem])
    val anOrder = CustomerOrder(Seq(
        OrderableItem(Chips, 2), OrderableItem(Fish, 1)
    ))
}

object Customer extends App{
    val system = ActorSystem("CustomerSystem", Configs.customerConfig)
    val shopAddress = "akka://ShopSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/user/Staff" 
    system.actorFor(shopAddress) ! new ChipShopOrder().anOrder
}

object ChipShop extends App{
    class Staff extends Actor{
        def receive = { case order => println("Received: "+order) }
    }

    ActorSystem("ShopSystem", Configs.shopConfig).actorOf(Props[Staff], "Staff")
}
```

Comment: I'd guess that this is completely unrelated to Akka. Remove all Akka stuff and just output anOrder to an ObjectOutputStream and then just read it in from there. Other than that it could have something to do with: https://groups.google.com/group/scala-language/tree/browse_frm/month/2012-02/129efeb6c1cf857a?rnum=81&_done=%2Fgroup%2Fscala-language%2Fbrowse_frm%2Fmonth%2F2012-02%3F

Comment: You're right, I can replicate with OOS.  Thanks for the link.  I guess it's a Scala bug then, the status of which I'm yet to decipher.

Comment: Well, Akka lets you define your own serializers so you could easily define a serializer for your own messages and handle the marshalling and unmarshalling there. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/serialization.html